# rsync filter: not finding the filter file

Tags: rsync

Wrote a shell script to aid me in deployment of website. Everything finally comes together as supposed, but the rsync command refuses to work.

```
rsync --chmod="ug+rwx" -e="ssh" --filter="merge '/.deploy/filters'" --dry-run "/var/www/vhosts/staging/myhost.com/httpdocs/" "me@myhost.com:/var/www/vhosts/myhost.com/domains/myhost.com/httpdocs"
```

gives:
`rsync: failed to open exclude file '/.deploy/filters': No such file or directory (2)`

Changing filter file path to full (relative to root) does not fix the problem; only the path in the reported error changes:

```
--filter="merge /.deploy/filters"
```

gives:
`invalid modifier sequence at 'd' in filter rule: .deploy`

Very frustrating and discouraging. Please, can someone explain?

**UPDATE**

Thought I need to clarify things a bit.
Using `--filter="merge 'path'"` without single quotes always gives the `invalid modifier sequence` error.

```
--filter="merge '/relative/to/rsync/root/path'"
```

gives the `no such file or directory` error, as well as using

```
--filter="merge '/relative/to/rsync/root/path'"
```

and

```
--filter="merge '/absolute/path'"
```

and

```
--filter="merge 'relative/path'"
```

Comment: My guess is that you're not aware that `/.deploy/filters` is an absolute path, and that you mean `.deploy/filters` instead.

Comment: @reinierpost I am aware of that. However, I am also under the impression that paths used with `rsync` are "absolute" relative to the rsync source directory. Besides, I already mentioned the 'invalid modifier sequence' error. Are you sure that the slash is the problem?

Comment: The example in the manpage is `merge /etc/rsync/default.rules`, clearly that refers to an absolute path. Why are you using quotes around the filename? On Unixy systems it's a better policy to avoid quotes by avoiding any characters in your filenames that are special to the shell. You never know how any particular tool is going to treat quotes.

Comment: @reinierpost I use quotes because, as explained before, if I use `merge .deploy/filters`, I get a `invalid modifier sequence`. In other words, I have tried it before. I also explained that I have already tried absolute path. Whenever I have an absolute path, if it is without quotes, it will complain about `invalid modifier sequence`. If I backslash-escape the full-stop in the folder name (`--filter="merge var/etc/www/vhosts/staging/myhost/httpdocs/\.deploy"`), we're back to `failed to open exclude file`. I know the file is there. I can `cd` into the directory, and see it in `ls` output.

Comment: In any case, why would the dot be a special character to `rsync`? It is a perfectly valid and legal filename character. Edit: Sorry, that `etc` part is extra in the previous comment.

Comment: Ok, so the `.` (dot) character in `filter` value is a special character. Given that, what I don't understand is why the rule starting with an explicit `merge` modifier gets further scanned for modifiers, instead of being interpreted literally? And, why the `invalid modifier syntax` error still occurs in the absolute version of the path, where the dot is **not** the first character? Even further, with the dot being quoted or escaped, why the `No such file or directory` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what was happening...

If used with single quotes, they were interpreted literally as part of the file name ( as @reinierpost suggested). Used without, the file `.deploy/filters` was being read and parsed. However, that file contained 1 line (which I failed to mention in the original description):

```
.deploy
```

It is this rule that `rsync` was complaining about, not the original filter file path.

So, confirmed, the right way is to use the `filter` arguments modifier value without single quotes.

Comment: Aargh ... so the problem was lack of clarity in the error messages.